# Hint for finding $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{\large{\ln(n)}}}$

Tags: limits

Can anyone provide me a hint for finding the limit of the function:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{\large{\ln(n)}}}$$

Comment: Suppose $y = (1+n^2)^{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}}$. Try to find the limit of $\ln(y)$

Comment: Whenever something is raised to the power of something, think of taking the $ln$ of the entire expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $  \ln[(1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{ln(n)}}]$

Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } \ln[(1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{ln(n)}}] =\frac{1}{ln(n)}\ln(1+n^{2}) = \frac{ln(1+n^{2})}{ln(n)}$

Use L'Hôpital's rule

Remember to undo the natural log afterward.

If this is too vague, I can add more

Comment: Do I need to perform log series expansion?

Comment: That should be clearer

Comment: Ohh gotcha ! I got $e^{2}$ finallly. Thanks :)

Comment: Why you used L'Hopital's rule? $\ln(n^2+1)\sim\ln n^2 =2\ln n$.

Comment: Because $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } = \frac{ln(1+n^{2})}{ln(n)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$ , so L'Hopital's is my first instinct. But your method appears to work just as well

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\quad y = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } (1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{\large{\ln(n)}}}$

$\implies \ln{y}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\ln {\Big((1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{\ln(n)}}\Big)}$

$\implies \ln{y}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }{\frac{1}{\large{\ln{n}}}}\ln {(1+n^{2})}\quad \quad ~which ~is~ \frac{\infty}{\infty} ~form$

Therefore applying L.H. Rule here , we have

$\ln{y}=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{2n^2}{n^2+1}$

$\implies \ln{y}=2$

So $~y=e^2$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\log\left((1+n^2)^{\large\frac1{\log(n)}}\right)
&=\frac{\log(1+n^2)}{\log(n)}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2\log(n)+\log\left(1+\tfrac1{n^2}\right)}{\log(n)}\\[6pt]
&=2+\frac{\log\left(1+\tfrac1{n^2}\right)}{\log(n)}
\end{align}
$$
Note that
$$
0\le\frac{\log\left(1+\tfrac1{n^2}\right)}{\log(n)}\le\frac{\log(2)}{\log(n)}
$$

Answer (score 0):

When $n$ starts to be large, $n^2+1\approx n^2$, $\log(1+n^2)\approx \log(n^2)=2\log(n)$ and then the limit as shown is previous answers.

For sure, if you want more than the limit itself, you could use series $$\log(1+n^2)=\log(n^2)+\log(1+\frac 1{n^2})=2\log(n)+\frac 1{n^2}+\cdots$$ $$\frac{\log(1+n^{2})}{\log(n)}=2+\frac 1{n^2\log(n)}+\cdots$$ which shows how the limit is approached. $$ (1+n^{2})^{\frac{1}{\large{\ln(n)}}}=e^2+\frac{e^2}{n^2 \log(n)}
   +\cdots$$